# include in document.referrer in "else if"

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, referrer

I have this script that displays a modal if no cookie. 
the first if, if the cookie exists it hides the modal,
and the "ELSE" if there is no cookie, it will display it.

I need to add a document.referer condition as below.

Besides verifying the cookie if it does not exist check the referer (the same function below), and only then display the modal.

The code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (jQuery.cookie('visits') > 0.5) {
    jQuery('#active-popup').hide();
    jQuery('#popup-container').hide();
    jQuery('html, body').removeAttr('style');
  } else {
    var pageHeight = jQuery(document).height();
    jQuery('<div id="active-popup"></div>').insertBefore('body');
    jQuery('#active-popup').css("height", pageHeight);
    jQuery('#popup-container').show();
    jQuery('html, body', window.parent.document).css({
      'overflow': 'hidden',
      'height': '100%'
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popup-container').css({
      'left': (Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 3) + '%'
    })
    $('#popup-container').css({
      'top': (Math.floor(Math.random() * 23) + 33) + '%'
    })
  });
});
```

The refer

```
  if (document.referrer) {
    facebook = /facebook.com/;
    if (facebook.test(document.referrer)) {

    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question ?
Are you just trying to change the "else" in "else if (document.referrer && facebook.test(document.referrer))" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `else` to `else if` with the condition you want.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  facebook = /facebook\.com/;
  if (jQuery.cookie('visits') > 0.5) {
    jQuery('#active-popup').hide();
    jQuery('#popup-container').hide();
    jQuery('html, body').removeAttr('style');
  } else if (document.referrer && facebook.test(document.referrer)) {
    var pageHeight = jQuery(document).height();
    jQuery('<div id="active-popup"></div>').insertBefore('body');
    jQuery('#active-popup').css("height", pageHeight);
    jQuery('#popup-container').show();
    jQuery('html, body', window.parent.document).css({
      'overflow': 'hidden',
      'height': '100%'
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popup-container').css({
      'left': (Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 3) + '%'
    })
    $('#popup-container').css({
      'top': (Math.floor(Math.random() * 23) + 33) + '%'
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar :D 
I changed the document.referer by document.referrer, but doesnt work. :( 
any idea?